# How to escape quotes in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm stuck with this:

I have a `ResultSet`to write in a html report. the `ResultSet`is

```
writer.write("<td><a href=>" + "../" + rsevidencia.getString("Evidencia") + 
             "<a/></td>");
```

But the link doesn't work because "Evidencia" is not into quotes, how to can I put quotes inside the `ResultSet` argument?

The `ResultSet` brings this 2013-10-10 09:15:00.110

Comment: wouldn't be easier to modify the sql call to add quotes?

Comment: Do you mean using `rsevidencia.getString("\"Evidencia\"")` instead? Hard to tell what you're asking for.

Comment: If is just about quotes, have you tried using `\"`?

Comment: You don't need to put quotes inside the result set. You need to put them inside the HTML output. By the way, JSP is so much easier with HTML than a servlet. You just have to do `<a href="${result.evidencia}">` and so on. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `"\"Evicendia\""`.
In java, you can access to escapate chars using `\`.

Comment: He needs to quote the _output_, not the column-name in the ResultSet.

Answer (score 1):

Escape a double-quote character in Java with a backslash character `\`: `\"` is one double-quote character.

```
//             Here's one -v                             Here's another -v
writer.write("<td><a href=\"../" + rsevidencia.getString("Evidencia") + "\">Label</a></td>");
```

[This Java tutorial page, section "Escape Sequences"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) covers escape characters in Java.

Comment: Did you notice that you're generating a link `<a>` without text, so there's no way it can be selected by user?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I focused on the string escapes; no I didn't notice.  I'll update.